# Can I use an API function for a directive's template URL?

Tags: angularjs, rest

I want to load an svg file dynamically from its path in the database I used RestApi to retrieve the path and the Svg file id and display the SVG in an  widget - "Id_Leaf"file id svg:

```
 // Get All information for LeafPlan

$scope.LoadLeaf = function (Id_Leaf) {
    RESTSummoner.DoGet(PATH_LEAF, "/" + Id_Leaf).succes(function (data) {
        $scope.Leaf = data;
        console.log(data);
    }).error(function () {

    });
}

module.directive('svgPlan', ['$compile', 'RESTSummoner', function ($compile, RESTSummoner) {

    return {
        restrict: "A",
        replace: true,
        controller: function ($scope) {  
            $scope.PATH_LEAF = 'SV_MAP_LEAF';
            alert($scope.PATH_LEAF);
        },
        templateUrl:'',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.PATH_LEAF = 'SV_MAP_LEAF';
            alert("coucou");
            RESTSummoner.DoGET(1).then(function (res) {
                alert("coucou");
                element.replaceWith(res.data)
                console.log(res.data);
                console.log(res.data);
            });
    }
    }
}])
```

Comment: What is `Api.DoGet(PATH)`?  Is that a function on scope?  A global function?

Comment: $scope.LoadLeaf = function () {

      API.DoGet(PATH_LEAF,"").succes(function (data) {


        }).

Answer (score -1):

You could make the request yourself and manually replace the directive element yourself using [`angular.element replaceWith()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

Something like:

```
module.directive('Plan', ['$compile','API', function ($compile, API) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",        
        templateUrl:  'Api.DoGet(PATH)',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            Api.DoGet(PATH).then(function(res){
               element.replaceWith(res.data)
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Hello, 
I do that but i have this error: ReferenceError: PATH_LEAF is not defined
    at Object.link

Comment: You haven't provided enough details in question

Comment: Hello

I want to load a svg file store on a server dynamically and store the file path in the database. I'm using a rest API to recover the path to the files and the id

Comment: Right but not clear where path details are created/stored for `PATH`

Comment: Hello charlie,
I used Rest Api to  recovred the path from database exemple  : .../plan0.svg and load him in the widget:
  RESTSummoner.DoGet(PATH_LEAF, "/" + Id_Leaf).succes(function (data)

Comment: Update question with service details and explain source of `Id_leaf`